# Searched from listed data should open by Firestore the new page

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I explain the situation with an example. I have 5 cards and when I click on these cards, they all open the same page (screen.dart). But I want each card to open a different page that I specified.
[image]

This is link of dart codes: https://files.fm/u/9kerqx7qg
This is link of working project:
https://usaupload.com/5x0k/search_firebase-20211215T192254Z-001.zip

Comment: This is pretty simple but I am not sure I can answer this by seeing this image.

Comment: I really need this. Please try to explain to me.

Comment: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtherScreen(data));
Navigator.push(context, route);

Comment: If this doesn't help you then let's connect

Comment: Nitishk72 connected and solved my problem, thanks a lot :)